# how to update json key value in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

we try to update the json data key value.we stored record in database **product_name** column like

> {"ar":"arabic product","en":""}

we try to achieve this both below two method

```
DB::table('products')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update(['productname->en' => 'english product']);

$post = product::find($product_id);
        $post->product_name = [$language => $edittitle];
        $post->save();
```

we want to update the json en key value.

Comment: what laravel version are you using? @GANESHJAGDHANE?

Comment: we using laravel 5.7 version

Comment: What exactly is the column name `product_name` or `productname`?

Comment: column name product_name

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy solution to update all the entries in one go:

```
Product::each(function ($product) {
    $productName = json_decode($product->product_name, true);
    $productName['en'] = 'english product';
    $product->product_name = json_encode($productName);
    $product->save();
});
```

If you want to update a single product, this should work:

```
$product = Product::find($product_id);
$productName = json_decode($product->product_name, true);
$productName['en'] = 'english product';
$product->product_name = json_encode($productName);
$product->save();
```

Comment: $product = product::find($product_id);
            product::each(function ($product) {
    $productName = json_decode($product->product_name, true);
    $productName['en'] = 'english product';
    $product->product_name = json_encode($productName);
    $product->save();
});
like this

Comment: I have updated my answer with how to change a single product. Hope this helps!

Comment: its shown me error like 
     "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" 
but when we comment this code in product model  
'
protected $casts = [
    'product_name' => 'array',
    ]; '
its works.

Comment: after commenting this 
" protected $casts = [ 'product_name' => 'array' ];" in product model insert is not working while inserting product_name need to mention as array.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to create that field with the right type in the migration file, the keyword we need there is `json`:

```
...
$table->json('productname');
...
```

Then we need to `cast` that attribute to the right type when retrieving it as `Eloquent model` by using `$casts` attribute on the model itself:

```
...
   /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'productname' => 'array'
    ];
...
```

Then we can access and save data for this attribute like so:

```
$myModel = product::find(1);
$myModel->productname['en'] = 'something';
// or
$myModel->productname = ['en' => 'something']; // This will override the whole attribute
```

For further details you can take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: thank you '$myModel->product_name = ['en' => 'something']' work for me but This will override the whole attribute we just want to update en key value. we also use $myModel->product_name['en'] = 'something'; it's return error message 
"Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Models\user\product::$product_name has no effect"

Comment: this is my model ' protected $casts = [
    'product_name' => 'array'
    ];'

Comment: Please remove `__get` and `__set` magic methods from your model in order for it to work properly. This is because `Model` class that each of your models `extends` from has those methods implemented :) @GANESHJAGDHANE

Comment: @Nikola-remove __get and __set magic methods from your model , sory not getting what exactly do

Comment: Do you have `__set()` and `__get()` methods inside your `product` model?

Comment: Did you load the `post` from database before assigning values to it's json attribute? `$post = product::find($product_id);`

Comment: yes when we store arabic product we store the record in ar key  '{"ar":"arabic product","en":""}'  and then when we update we  select  english local and store the product name in en key value

Comment: no when we using '$myModel->productname['en'] = 'something';'
 it's return error message "Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Models\user\product::$product_name has no effect" we not use any __set() and __get() methods inside  product model only write 
protected $casts = [
        'productname' => 'array'
    ];
and belongsToMany  and hasMany relationship's functions

Comment: That error message means you are setting the value from another place to that same attribute, could you look for such a case and post it in your answer, it must be related with this particular case u posted the question for