# Laravel : set json nested value and save model using ->save()

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to set a json nested value `mymodel->myjsoncolumn->foo->bar = 123` and then use `mymodel->save()` to save it? If yes, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to update json key value in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54342010/how-to-update-json-key-value-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a way to do it like you are asking.
The only way you can it is like:

```
$existingJsonObj  = json_decode(mymodel->myjsoncolumn);
$existingJsonObj->foo->bar = 123;
$mymodel->myjsoncolumn = json_encode($existingJsonObj);
$mymodel->save()
```